# Azure Functions in Visual Studio: Accessing Azure Configured Application Settings Locally

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm working on an Azure Functions project in Visual Studio and facing an issue with accessing application settings that are configured in Azure. I have set certain configuration values in the Azure portal under my Function App's application settings. However, I'm unable to access these settings in my local development environment.

**Local Setup:**

- Function App with several functions developed in PowerShell.
- Using local.settings.json for local development settings.

**local.settings.json**
[image]

**Issue:**

When I run my function locally and attempt to access environment variables set in local.settings.json, they return empty. I've tried accessing the variables using the $env:VariableName syntax in PowerShell, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
Write-Host "Storage Account Connection String: $($env:klantacontainer)"
Write-Host "Test Variable: $($env:TestVariable)"
```

**# In my run.ps1 file**

```
$storageAccountConnectionString = $env:klantacontainer
Write-Host "Storage Account Connection String: $storageAccountConnectionString"

$testVariable = $env:TestVariable
Write-Host "Test Variable: $testVariable"
```

**Attempts:**

- I've ensured local.settings.json is located at the root of the project.
- Restarted the Azure Functions host after making changes.
- Checked for syntax errors in local.settings.json.
- Tried both accessing the variable directly and with the APPSETTING_ prefix.

**Application settings**

[image]

Comment: I am able to get the value from local settings file https://i.imgur.com/elzB1l9.png

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin thanks for letting me know! I am so lost on why it's not working haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to get the values from **local settings** file using the code given below.

**run.ps1**-

```
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

# Write to the Azure Functions log stream.
Write-Host "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."

Write-Host "Test Variable: $($env:TestVariable)"

# Interact with query parameters or the body of the request.
$name = $Request.Query.Name
if (-not $name) {
    $name = $Request.Body.Name
}

$body = "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."

if ($name) {
    $body = "Hello, $name. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
}

# Associate values to output bindings by calling 'Push-OutputBinding'.
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Body = $body
})
```

**local.settings**-

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME_VERSION": "7.2",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "powershell",
    "TestVariable": "TestValue"
  }
}
```

**host.json**-

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
  },
  "managedDependency": {
    "enabled": true
  }
}
```

I am able to get the value of **TestVariable** as shown below-

[image]

[image]